# How do I know if a file has finished copying?

Tags: python, windows, file, copy

I've been given a simple file-conversion task: whenever an MP4 file is in a certain directory, I do some magic to it and move it to a different directory. Nice and straightforward, and easy to automate.

However, if a user is copying some huge file into the directory, I worry that my script might catch it mid-copy, and only have half of the file to work with.

Is there a way, using Python 3 on Windows, to check whether a file is done copying (in other words, no process is currently writing to it)?

EDIT: To clarify, I have no idea how the files are getting there: my script just needs to watch a shared network folder and process files that are put there. They might be copied from a local folder I don't have access to, or placed through SCP, or downloaded from the web; all I know is the destination.

Answer (score 0):

you could try first comparing the size of the file initially, or alternatively see if there are new files in the folder, capture the name of the new file and see if its size increases in x time, if you have a script, you could show the code....

Answer (score -2):

You can compare the file size  `the source file` and `the destination file` periodically.

```
If the file sizes are different: Not done.
If the file sizes are the same: Done.
```

Comment: What if the file is on a local drive? Say they upload to a shared network folder, he wont be able to access that.

Comment: As @AriVictor says, unfortunately I don't know where they're copying from: I'm writing a script that'll watch a shared folder and process anything put into it, but I have no control over how the files get into that folder.

Comment: How about checking the new file size, as @MariasFigueroa answers.